# Ignore SQS visibility timeout for failed lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I have simple lambda in NodeJS that always fails that consumes messages from SQS (code below).
As far as I understand, when the lambda fails, the SQS still waits *visibility timeout* before it retries to redeliver the message again. **Is there a way to stop message visibility timeout when the processing lambda failed?**. I want message, that failed to be processed by lambda, to be redelivered immediately. Note that I am only interested in SQS-Lambda integration, I don't care about different ways to process messages.

My case: in my project the lambda sometimes won't even start, because it is missing some assets (for example because of dependency upgrade). Therefore, I can't manually call [`ChangeMessageVisibility`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_ChangeMessageVisibility.html) manually. The SQS queue has visibility timeout of 20 minutes, and there are 5 deliveries attempts before the message is moved into DLQ. I have alarm that notifies me when DLQ receives any message, so I know there is something wrong with the lambda.
Because of the visibility timeout, it takes almost 2 hours!! before I receive the notification.

Example CDK project that has 5 redeliveries and visibility timeout of 5 minutes (so it takes almost half an hour to move the message into DLQ) is here:

```js
const env = {
    account: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_ACCOUNT,
    region: process.env.CDK_DEFAULT_REGION,
};

const app = new App();
const stack = new Stack(app, 'sqs-lambda', { env });

const dlq = new Queue(stack, 'dlq', {});
const q = new Queue(stack, 'queue', {
    deadLetterQueue: {
        queue: dlq,
        maxReceiveCount: 5,
    },
    visibilityTimeout: Duration.minutes(5),
});

const fn = new Function(stack, 'lambda', {
    code: Code.fromInline("exports.handler = () => { console.log('executed'); throw new Error('error'); }"),
    runtime: Runtime.NODEJS_16_X,
    handler: 'index.handler',
    events: [new SqsEventSource(q, {
        batchSize: 1,
    })],
})
```

Comment: can you reduce the delivery attempt to 1?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra thank you for your tip, but that doesn't solve the problem. Yes, it shorter the interval, but there are still the 20 minutes visibility timeout after the first invocation. Also, in case there is some 3rd party error somewhere, that would discard the message into DLQ immediately, instead of trying again.

Comment: You should probably setup a separate alert on the invocation failures metric, or something in your Lambda's logs, to notify you earlier that there is a problem, instead of trying to change the behavior of your SQS queue.

Comment: is it possible for you to control when the source will send a message to the queue? like is it in your control?

Comment: @JatinMehrotra yes, my other service is sending messages to the SQS.

Comment: since you can control, set visibility timeout to 0 and by default send all messages with `message timers`  of 20 mins, if there is failure, send message with 0 min message failure, if at all lambda does not start when you send message with message timer 0 seconds you still have 4 delivery attempt.
docs for message timers https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-message-timers.html